# How to refresh text on a canvas Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm coding a game for a school project. I currently have a canvas created called "fightScreen". I'm trying to make a button run a function the subtracts two int variables and then updates text on the canvas to that value. The text is already present on the canvas before this button is clicked.

```
def enemyHealth():
    global eneLives
    eneLives = eneLives - attackPower

coinsText = fightScreen.create_text(100, 30, text = "Coins:", font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("gold"))
coinsCounter = fightScreen.create_text(210, 30, text = coins, font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("gold"))
healthCounter = fightScreen.create_text(595, 30, text = eneLives, font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("red"))
healthText = fightScreen.create_text(470, 30, text = "Health:", font = ("calibri", 35), fill = ("red"))    
attack = fightScreen.create_window(170, 380, window = Button(fightScreen, text = "Attack!", font = ("calibri" , 20), command = enemyHealth))
openShop = fightScreen.create_window(80, 380, window = Button(fightScreen, text = "Shop", font = ("calibri" , 20), command = shop))

mainloop()
```

This is the code snippet. The button is "attack".